# Jmeter displays doubled results when running in non gui mode

Tags: jmeter

I have a Test plan which when I run in the Gui Mode execute the sampler one time, but when I start the Test Plan from the command line I get the sampler to be running twice.

I have deleted the result.jtl file to insure that the results are not accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your test plan it's hard or even impossible to say what's the reason as there are too many possible options, the most straightforward I can think of is:

1. You have a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) (or two) somewhere in the test plan configured to write data into the same file which you specify via `-l` command-line argument
2. You have `resultcollector.action_if_file_exists=APPEND` property defined somewhere

So try out the following way of running the test:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -f -Jresultcollector.action_if_file_exists=DELETE
```

where:

- `-f` forces JMeter to overwrite the .jtl results file
- `resultcollector.action_if_file_exists=DELETE` property does the same for Listeners

More information:

- [Full list of JMeter command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)